# Top links per JobID in Exacttarget (Greatest n per group)

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I am trying to query the _Click data view to find the top performing links in any given job. I have wrote my query to report back the top 3 links in every job, to be grouped by job id, link, then links clicked descending by counting the subscriber key.

`SELECT c.JobID, c.LinkContent, count(c.SubscriberKey)
FROM _Click c
WHERE (
    SELECT count(AccountID)
    FROM _Click as d
    WHERE d.LinkContent = c.LinkContent AND count(d.SubscriberKey) >= count(c.SubscriberKey)
    ) <=3
ORDER BY c.JobID, c.LinkContent, clicked DESC`

This code generates syntax error requiring that I have TOP in my select statement which I don't want because I have no idea how many rows (JobID) it will return.

I also tried removing the ORDER BY line but it generates a new syntax code stating that I cannot use an aggregrate in the WHERE clause. For those curious, I adapted this code from: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFMC runs on SQL Server, so your MySQL script isn't going to work.  Needs to be a T-SQL query.

Something like this should work:

```
select
y.jobid
, y.linkcontent
, y.counter
, y.ranking
from (
  select
  x.jobid
  , x.linkcontent
  , x.counter
  , dense_rank() over (partition by x.jobid order by x.counter desc) ranking
  from (
    select 
    c.jobid
    , c.linkcontent
    , count(c.subscriberkey) counter
    from _Click c
    group by c.jobid, c.linkcontent
  ) x
) y
where y.ranking <= 3
order by y.jobid, y.ranking asc
```

The innermost sub-query will total clicks by `jobid` and `linkcontent`.  The query outside of that will rank the rows by number of clicks.  The outermost will limit it to the top 3 for each job and link.

Comment: Thank you explaining how I went wrong. I am new to SQL and SFMC and did not realize how fundamentally different they are.

FYI to others, I needed to modify Adam's answer by adding a `code`TOP`code` after `code`SELECT`code` to make SFMC happy and I also changed my criteria to get exactly the results I was looking for. Adam provided the core logic.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs why did you count subscriberkey and not linkcontent?